# ¿Como recibir variables de codeigniter sin tener que cargar la vista?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Para editar los datos de una persona tengo un boton el cual al oprimir toma ese id y lo envia no por ajax sino directamente al controlador con el id para que haga la validacion y traiga los datos...

Lo que deseo es que esos datos me los muestre en una ventana modal pero con datos enviados directamente del php (codeigniter), normalmente se usa asi...

```
if($answer)
{
 $data = array('nombre' => $answer->nombre_personal,
               'apellido' => $answer->apellido_personal)
 $this->load->view(index,$data);
}
```

Sucede que como ya la vista esta cargada en la `funcion index` no puedo recargarla para que me muestre los datos, entonces de que otra manera podría tomar esos sin cargar la vista nuevamente?

Pdta: No se requiere el uso de ajax..

Agradeceria su colaboracion y el interes.

Comment: Sin usar ajax casi no le veo sentido, intenta usando la funcion load de jquery https://api.jquery.com/load/ apuntando a la funcion de tu controlador

Comment: el problema esque si quiero recibir esos datos con jquery (ajax) me tocaria hacerlo de la siguiente manera $('#nombre').val(answer[0].nombre_empleado); y no es lo que busco realizar en este momento

Comment: Claro por eso intenta usando la funcion load de jquery, y colocando el resultado en tu modal

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo para tener la idea mas clara?

Comment: Sin ajax no puedes hacerlo, porque implica recargar la página y eso implícitamente implica renderear la vista. Incluso aunque lo hagas usando load, estarás rendereando la vista. Necesitas ajax y además hacer un endpoint que entregue $data formateada como json y no como html

Comment: @amenadiel te agradezco la respuesta...te hago una pregunta, ok, yo uso ajax para traer los datos y pasar el valor por medio de un id...entonces como hago yo para listar esos datos en un select?...ejemplo:
"$('#ciudades').append('<option value="' + resultado[0].id_ciudad + '">' + resultado[0].nombre_ciudad + '</option>');"....
usando esto claramente voy a mostrar la ciudad con la cual fue registrado el usuario..pero entonces como listo el resto de ciudades por si el usuario no era de esa ciudad para modificarlo?

Comment: Tendrías el select ya rendereado desde el principio, con todas las ciudades. El ajax sólo te permitiría cambiar cuál es la opción seleccionada, sin usar append a las opciones ya existentes

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer usando ***jquery***, creando una función en la controladora donde imprimas el contenido en un json, te dejo un ejemplo:

> En codeigniter:

```
public function getmodal(){

   $output = array('nombre'=>'Pedro', 'apellido'=>'Gonzales');
   echo json_encode($output);
}
```

> En jquery:

```
path=baseurl+"controladora/getmodal"    

$.post(path, function(result){

              $(selector 1 del modal).html(result.nombre);
              $(selector 2 del modal).html(result.apellido);
            },'json');
```

> Para el caso del id solo lo tienes que incorporar en el $.post para pasarlo a la controladora y lo captura dentro de la función con $this->input->post(); 
>   [$.post jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)